# How do I create global utility functions in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need a place to stick global referentially transparent utility methods. These should be accessible from everywhere in rails (Models, Views, Controllers, and everywhere else). e.g.:

```
bool = GlobalUtilities.to_bool "false"
unicorn = GlobalUtilities.make_me_a "unicorn"
```

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Do you want to say `GlobalUtilities.make_me_a "pancake"` or just `make_me_a "pancake"`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could always stick these in `/lib` and require them. See [bricker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7737062/456584) -- you can require these modules to be loaded from your `application.rb`, which will make them accessible everywhere.

See: [Rails lib directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7736773/rails-lib-directory)

Comment: Also Bill's answer isn't a bad idea if you're trying to add functionality to preexisting datatypes.

Answer (score 3):

I would make a descriptively-named file for each behavior that your are hoping to achieve, and collect them in /lib (or, better yet, an engine). Then, mix your desired functionality into the  class you hope to extend. For example, in the scenario you described, you could add a `parse_boolean` method directly to `String`. Pretty slick stuff.

/lib/add_parse_boolean_to_string.rb

```
class String

  def parse_boolean
    self == 'true' # or whatever...
  end

end
```