# Where should I put shrine image_uploader file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shrine

I'm using [shrine](https://shrinerb.com/) for image uploading in my project. I'm trying to follow this guide: [Getting Started/Eager Processing](https://shrinerb.com/docs/getting-started#eager-processing)

I am not sure where should I put `image_uploader.rb` in my project.

FYI, here is the code for `image_uploader.rb`:

```rb
require 'image_processing/mini_magick'

class ImageUploader < Shrine
    Attacher.derivatives do |original|
        magick = ImageProcessing::MiniMagick.source(original)
        { 
          large:  magick.resize_to_limit!(1200, 1200),
          medium: magick.resize_to_limit!(640, 640),
          small:  magick.resize_to_limit!(180, 180),
        }
    end
end
```

It does not seem to belong to `lib` directory according to [this answer(Rails lib directory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7736773/rails-lib-directory) and this [blog post(What Code Goes in the Lib/ Directory?)](https://codeclimate.com/blog/what-code-goes-in-the-lib-directory/).

And it is not a helper or a controller.

Where should I put it into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to putting image_uploader.rb in uploaders folder, but usually doesn't exist folders so, you have to make folders, and I recommend these sample [Getting started Shrine](https://github.com/shrinerb/shrine),
[Demo code](https://github.com/erikdahlstrand/shrine-rails-example)

```
yourapp/app/uploaders
```